# Discord.Net give role based on user input

Tags: vb.net, discord, discord.net

so I created a role command but I the command to give the role based on user input. I don't have much working right now but this is what I currently have.

```
Imports Discord
Imports Discord.Commands
Imports Discord.WebSocket

<Group("giverole")>
Public Class giverole
    Inherits ModuleBase(Of ICommandContext)
    ' Private user = Context.User
    ' Private role As IRole
    '<Remainder> ByVal r As String
    'Dim author = Context.Message.Author

    <Command("weebers")>
    Private Async Function giveRole() As Task
        'Await DirectCast(author, SocketGuildUser).AddRoleAsync(role)
        'Await CType(Context.User, SocketGuildUser).AddRoleAsync(role)
        'Dim role = Context.Guild.Roles.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.Name.ToString() = "WEEBERS")
        'Await user.AddRoleAsync(role)
        'Dim user = Context.User
        'Dim role = Context.Guild.Roles.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.Name = "WEEBERS")

        Dim roleid As ULong = 486599202093269012
        Dim role = DirectCast(Context.Message.Channel, IGuildChannel).Guild.GetRole(roleid)
        Await DirectCast(Context.User, SocketGuildUser).AddRoleAsync(role)
        Await ReplyAsync(role.ToString)

    End Function

End Class
```

Even though this could compile it does not give me the role even with just the command -giverole. I had this working last night but now when I woke up it broke giving me an error of an object not getting referenced. Somehow I managed to get rid of that error but now the role will not get assigned. Now what I would really want to do is give the user the role based on his input. As you can see by my comments. I've been trying for a while on how to get this to work.

Comment: What does this have to do with C#? It looks like you have a VB.NET issue and are looking for a VB.NET solution

Comment: Sorry edited out C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would suggest using `SocketCommandContext` instead of `ICommandContext`.
Second, I believe your commands are meant to be public in order to be discovered.

As far as the code goes, if using `SocketCommandContext`

```vb
    Inherits ModuleBase(Of SocketCommandContext)

    <Command("weebers")>
    Public Async Function giveRole() As Task
        Dim roleid As ULong = 486599202093269012
        Dim role = Context.Guild.GetRole(roleid)
        
        Await DirectCast(Context.User, SocketGuildUser).AddRole(role)
        Await ReplyAsync(role.Name)
    End Function
```

This code actually gives the role to the user that executed the command. Not sure if that's what you want or not.

> NOTE: You should be able to pass both the user and the role as parameters to the command so in theory you can give any user any role (some whatever restriction applied to specified scenarios)

Comment: Hello again! You're right my function had to be public for it to be recognized. At first, it didn't want to work but after I removed (Of SocketCommandContext) it worked. Thanks a lot. I've been trying to get this to work for about 3 days now and couldn't put my finger around it.

Answer (score -1):

This Should help you out now you just gotta add checking for which command is begin sent and assign the role based on

```
Private Async Function OnMessage(rawmsg As SocketUserMessage) As Task Handles Discord.MessageReceived
    If rawmsg.Author.IsBot = True Then
        'ignoring msgs from bots
    Else
        Dim context As New SocketCommandContext(Discord, rawmsg)
        If rawmsg.Content.StartsWith("-giverole") Then 'adding the command
            Dim role As String = rawmsg.Content.Replace("-giverole ", "") 'removing -giverole from it

            If role = "Admin" OrElse role = "bots" Then 'blacklist
                Await rawmsg.Channel.SendMessageAsync(rawmsg.Author.Mention & " nice try")
            Else
                For Each r In context.Guild.Roles
                    If r.ToString = role Then 'role exists
                        Dim role2 = context.Guild.Roles.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.Name = r.ToString)
                        Await DirectCast(context.User, SocketGuildUser).AddRoleAsync(role2)
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Hello! I'm not sure how to do the checking? I was thinking of an if statement but I'm not exactly sure how to get that to work.

Comment: This is what I tried to do but not sure if this is how it is supposed to be.  https://hastebin.com/ezirakicid.php   I get no errors but nothing happens. guessing it does nothing since the if statement didn't return true. Also, I'm not sure but I had to add another variable "Private WithEvents Discord As DiscordSocketClient"

Comment: Can you explain to me how you want your command to work?

Comment: basically if someone types -giverole rolename     <it gives them the role rolename. Now having a sort of a check would be nice because I would like for them not to get the admin role.

Comment: There is 2 ways of going about this either a function based on a whitelist or blacklist

Whitelist you would have to list every single role that is available.
Blacklist you would just List the ones that are not supose to be obtainable

which one would you rather want?

Comment: Well, the roles I don't want obtainable are about 2 roles. Admin and bots. I think Blacklist would be better.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your help but I think something is just wrong on my end... I'm not sure what's going on because I replaced Admin with the name of my role, Weeb God, and bots with, Bots, and nothing has changed. one of my roles is called Weebers. I do -giverole Weebers but the role is not given to me. in the role hierarchy, the role Bots, and the given role the bot has, in this instance, Rulmar is above all the other roles and both Bots and Rulmar have admin privileges. Is there anything else I am supposed to do?

Comment: Did you give your Bot Admin privileges after you invited him since that wont work?

Comment: this is the whole class. I'm not sure if this is of any use this is it. https://hastebin.com/wocecabuwu.bash      Do you think if I showed my command handler it could help you know how the commands are being processed? @dome

Comment: yes but I kicked the bot out of my server and added admin privileges and then invited it back.

Comment: give this a try with your api key
https://pastebin.com/gNGePtmN

Comment: My main is inside a different file. https://hastebin.com/depagutile.sql   < that has both my command handler and main module. My token and prefix are saved in a json file.

Comment: If `FirstOrDefault` is being used to find the role by name, why is there a need for the `For` loop? Additionally, the lib provides an inbuilt command service that saves you from having to do string parsing logic in the message received event  handler.